# Android migrate from xml to compose : Backend Internal error: Exception during IR lowering

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I was start migration android xml to compose. i got following error

> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.BackendException: Backend Internal
> error: Exception during IR lowering File being compiled

Configuration

```
composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }


buildFeatures {
  
    dataBinding = true
    compose = true
}


//compose
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:1.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.5.10")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
```